# Issue with selecting td cell with Selenium via javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

[image]

[image]

This is the HTML, I need to select the TextField, which is selected (input id = "login" name="j_username"......)
This is my JS file now

```
var webdriver = require ('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('https://student.tuke.sk/student/home.mais;jsessionid=18C8A365CEB230018870BF5F6884F3F9');
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="login"]/input')).click();
driver.sleep(1500);
driver.findElement(By.xpath('/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@id="login"]'))
.sendKeys('rk096jv');
```

I simply cannot select it right, it always tells me that NoSuchElementError is unable to find a element. Is there any way to select the field and write my credentials there ? Thank you

Comment: Make sure HTML is present before running the script

Comment: Screenshot of the page is fine. Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: You need to use a wait and find it using the name.  Selenium handles that.

Comment: I see you set until, but you ever use it.  Why aren't you using it?

Answer (score 1):

Without the full HTML, it's hard to say why your locator isn't working. My guess is that somewhere in that 15ish levels of the DOM in your locator is a problem. That's generally why locators that are that deep should be avoided. I would do something more simple like this CSS selector

```
#loginForm #login
```

Make sure you add a proper wait (wait for visible) instead of a `sleep()`.